# clone Postgres schema without pg_dump

Tags: postgresql

I need a way to systematically clone Postgres schemas to another database, without data, via SQL queries. I can not use `pg_dump` (because well, it's complicated). The solution would be something like:

1. Connect to database to clone.
2. Get schema
3. Connect to new database (where we are going to clone to)
4. Execute schema script

Is it possible to get the queries that `pg_dump` uses to dump a schema via sql queries or similar? E.g. to run pg_dump via sql editor?

**Update:**

With cloning schema i mean a particular `schema` (e.g. `public`) and its contents.

Comment: Using pg_dump is by far the easiest option to clone your database. Or get a SQL editor/IDE that has this option as well, like DataGrip.

Comment: Using `pg_dump` might be complicated in your situation, but trying to do it any other way will be vastly more complicated.

Comment: 1) When you say schems do you mean all the objects definitions in the database or a particular `schema` e.g. `public` and its contents? **Add answer as update to question**. 2) How  is this `pg_dump -d <db_name> -U <some_user> -p <some_port> -s -f schema_only.sql` then `psql  -d <other_db> -U <user> -p <other_port> -f schema_only.sql` complicated?

Comment: Using `pg_dump` is complicated because I have a SQL client running on top of Python that is able to execute SQL queries on the postgres database. I don't have `pg_dump` available. But it seems I will have to install it as well on the stack if no other option is feasible.

Answer (score 0):

This Python 3 code will replicate the source database's schemas and tables to a target database using the `psycopg` package.

If you wish to replicate nullables, keys or indexes, you may need to further refine the `CREATE TABLE` query that is generated by this code. You could easily save these `CREATE TABLE` scripts to file for separate use or execution.

There is also a small block at bottom that will copy the table data, should you wish to do so.

```
import psycopg


source = {
    'host': 'source_host', 
    'port': '5432', 
    'dbname': 'source_database',
    'user': 'postgres', 
    'password': 'postgres'
    }

target = {
    'host': 'target_host', 
    'port': '5432', 
    'dbname': 'target_database',
    'user': 'postgres', 
    'password': 'postgres'
    }

sourcedb = psycopg.connect(**source)
targetdb = psycopg.connect(**target)

with sourcedb:
    with targetdb:
        targetdb.autocommit = False
        with sourcedb.cursor() as sourceCursor:
            with targetdb.cursor() as targetCursor:
                # get list of schemas in database
                query = f"""SELECT      schema_name 
                            FROM        information_schema.schemata
                            WHERE           schema_name not in ('pg_catalog',
                                                                'pg_toast', 
                                                                'information_schema')
                            ORDER BY    schema_name ASC;"""
                sourceCursor.execute(query)
                schemas = [tupleRow[0] for tupleRow in sourceCursor.fetchall()]

                for schema in schemas:
                    # get list of tables in schema
                    query = f"""SELECT      table_name 
                                FROM        information_schema.tables 
                                WHERE           table_schema = '{schema}' 
                                            AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
                                ORDER BY    table_name ASC;"""
                    sourceCursor.execute(query)
                    schemaTables = [tupleRow[0] for tupleRow in sourceCursor.fetchall()]

                    # create schema on target_database if not exists
                    query = f'CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS "{schema}";'
                    targetCursor.execute(query)

                    for table in schemaTables:
                        # generate a 'CREATE TABLE' query from source 
                        # table's column names and data types
                        query = f"""SELECT       column_name
                                                ,data_type
                                    FROM        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                                    WHERE           table_name = '{table}' 
                                                AND table_schema = '{schema}'
                                    ORDER BY    ordinal_position ASC;"""
                        sourceCursor.execute(query)
                        columns = ['"{}" {}\n'.format(i[0], i[1]) for i in sourceCursor.fetchall()]
                        columnsString = ' ,'.join(columns)
                        createTableQuery = f'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "{schema}"."{table}"\n( {columnsString});\n\n'

                        # run the CREATE TABLE on the target_database
                        targetCursor.execute(createTableQuery)

                        # uncomment this block to copy the data inside the tables
                        # from source_database to target_database
                        
                        # with sourceCursor.copy(f"COPY {schema}.{table} TO STDOUT;") as sourceCopy:
                        #     with targetCursor.copy(f"COPY {schema}.{table} FROM STDIN;") as targetWrite:
                        #         for data in sourceCopy:
                        #             targetWrite.write(data)

        targetdb.commit()
```

Comment: Thank you for your code @DevC. The issue with running queries directly is that it will be very difficult to systematically replicate schemas. On your code above, for example, you are missing constraints and other objects. As you say, we can include them, but the query is going to get quite big quite fast. Consider that  `pg_dump` has over 10,000 lines of code, so I don't think the purpose should be to replicate `pg_dump` because it's going to be quite difficult and a lot of queries. My question was more if we can somehow the `pg_dump` scripts directly from the SQL client.